# QGIS MSSQL Spatial Layer Instant Crash

Tags: qgis, sql-server

I am able to connect to the mssql server database and choose the table that contains the spatial data. However, as soon as the layer is added, I get the 'crash dumped' error with a message saying
"minidump written to C:"

- The database is hosted on azure
- On a smaller database, I can see the nodes/location display briefly before the crash occurs.
- I have tested the issue on a much smaller database that contained 1 row/entry and the crash still occurs but it's usually after I add another layer (e.g. open streetmap layer)

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting this crash from one of the 3 reasons below:

1: SRID not set on Geometry Column. To check the SRID, I use the following SQL code

```
SELECT *, GeometryColumn.STSrid FROM [DataBaseName].[dbo].[TableName]
```

2: Invalid Geometries in the Tables. To check the Invalid shapes, I use the following SQL

```
  SELECT * FROM [DataBaseName].[dbo].[TableName] WHERE GeometryColumn.STIsValid() = 0
```

3: No Primary Key Set on that table